"Cannot access a disposed context instance" when calling RoleManager<TRole>.RoleExistsAsync()
I have two projects that are similar ( because I wanted one to use to test stuff but nothing really changes from the other ), on the first one, everything works fine when I seed the User & Roles on startup but on the next one there's an issue I can't figure out and I'm getting this error:

Users = {"Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name: 'AppDbContext'."}

This happens when I run the 2nd project but it didn't happen on the previous one knowing that I haven't changed anything.
I've read that this issue happens when a controller or a method return async void but nowhere in my code do I have a method that returns that, only async Task<T>/async Task.
I've added comments where the debugger shows the issue happens:
CreateRoles.cs
public static class CreateRoles
{
    public static async Task SeedAsync(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IPasswordHasher passwordHasher)
    {
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        var applicationRoleAdmin = new ApplicationRole
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("cb0dc828-2755-4b3f-9035-788839dcc8cf"),
            Name = "Admin"
        };

    var applicationRoleUser = new ApplicationRole
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse("17fdc6f4-bffe-45e6-9ca6-adb0af6ffcc3"),
        Name = "User"
    };

    // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE HAPPENS, its on adminRoleExist that it breaks out of this class
    // and goes back to Program.cs which never happened on the 1st project <-------------
    var adminRoleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
    if (!adminRoleExist)
    {
        roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(applicationRoleAdmin);
    }

    var userRoleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User");
    if (!userRoleExist)
    {
        roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(applicationRoleUser);
    }

    var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        UserName = "whatever",
        FirstName = "whatever",
        LastName = "whatever",
        Email = "whatever",
        PhoneNumber = "whatever",
        CategoryId = whatever,
        SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        PasswordHash = passwordHasher.Hash(configuration["whatever"])
    };

    var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(applicationUser.Id.ToString());
    if (user == null)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = await userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser);
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "Admin");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "User");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
}

Program.cs
internal class Program
{
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

    IPasswordHasher passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    var servicesSetup = builder.Services;
    servicesSetup.AddApplicationServices();
    servicesSetup.AddPersistenceServicesProduction(configuration);
    servicesSetup.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        await DataHelper.ManageDataAsync(services, cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            // THIS IS WHERE THE DEBUGGER SHOWS THE ERROR, on userManager and goes to the catch statement <-------
            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();

            await CreateRoles.SeedAsync(
                userManager,
                roleManager,
                configuration,
                passwordHasher);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
}

DataHelper.cs
public static class DataHelper
    {

        public static async Task ManageDataAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            using AppDbContext db = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

            IEnumerable<String> pendingMigrationIds = 
                await db.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (pendingMigrationIds.Any())
            {
                await db.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

I know you don't have the 1st project to compare but I've literally copy pasted and changed nothing besides the namespace because it has a different name.
I tried without the using statement but was left with the same situation.
Complete StackTrace:

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetTEntity
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore5.get_Roles() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore5.FindByNameAsync(String normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1.d__33.MoveNext()
at ColdStoneOfSM.Persistence.Seed.CreateRoles.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\name\source\repos\My.Website\My.Persistence\Seed\CreateRoles.cs:line 30
at Program.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\name\source\repos\My.Website\My.API\Program.cs:line 55

UPDATE
Also, I figured something out, it seems that when I created a blank ASP.NET Core API that this code would run without any problem but when I use the web API template, it doesn’t work anymore.

Please [edit] your question to include the full complete exception stacktrace.

Added the full StackTrace

What is DataHelper.ManageDataAsync? does it using a database context?

My bad for not posting it, just did @JeremyLakeman

using AppDbContext db = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>() I suspected as much. You've disposed the scoped service. Don't do that. Service lifetime is the responsibility of the service provider.

What should I do exactly ? I don't really know honestly, a transient ?

Never using .... .GetService<>()

Oh let me try this

You're a genius @JeremyLakeman, thank you

Do you want to post an answer I can mark as the answer ?
